# Video stuttering when drawn to canvas on Chrome 63

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas, video

I'm running a loop drawing a playing video onto a canvas. it used to work smoothly until the last chrome update, where now the video is stuttering, jumping 2 frames ahead and then one back. the same code performs smoothly on firefox and opera.

i'm currently testing on chrome 63.0.3239.132.
has anyone stumbled upon this issue?

here's the code i test with:

```js
var canvas, context, video;
function drawingLoop() {
 window.requestAnimationFrame(drawingLoop);
 context.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
}

canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

video = document.createElement('video');
video.addEventListener("loadeddata", function() {
 canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
 canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
 context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 video.play();
 window.requestAnimationFrame(drawingLoop);
});
video.autoplay = false;
video.src = "http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4";
video.load();
```

Comment: that sample is only 5s, so it's hard to get a clear picture of what's going on, but as it plays smoothly once in the browser cache (chrome63, macOS) I'm guessing the issue is with the initial load of the video. Have you tried with other sources (especially something optimized for streaming)?

Comment: i have tried multiple videos from various sources, the result is the same.
in my use case waiting for the video to fully load is not possible.

Comment: drawing onto a canvas no bigger than 256x256, or disabling hardware acceleration makes the problem go away. alas, neither are viable solutions.
it's probably a GPU bug with the new chrome version.

Comment: for the video you're using, is it optimized for streaming (specifically the MOOV atom, which defaults to the end, relocated to the front) and delivered from a server that supports byte-range requests

Comment: @Offbeatmammal, regardless, it used to work on previous chrome versions and still works properly on other browsers. i don't always have control over the source video file so i was looking for a way around this new chrome bug that will allow to continue using the same sources as before. i did find a way in the mean time, which is a bit wasteful but works. i copy the video onto a canvas using webgl as a texture instead of copying using drawImage.